# How write test case for gatewayreasoncode to verify reason code is actually truncated in the test

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4

How write test case for gatewayreasoncode to verify reason code is actually truncated in the test.

```java
public String actionAndReturnRefundIdIfGenerated(TransactionReconciliationEventVO vo) {
        Payment payment = paymentManager.get(vo.getZRelatedObjectId());

        // Update payment object
        if (payment.getGatewayState() == GatewayState.Submitted) {
            payment.setGatewayState(GatewayState.Settled);
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(vo.getGatewayReconciliationStatus())) {
                payment.setGatewayReconciliationStatus(vo.getGatewayReconciliationStatus());
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(vo.getGatewayReconciliationReason())) {
                payment.setGatewayReconciliationReason(vo.getGatewayReconciliationReason());
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(vo.getPayoutId())) {
                payment.setPayoutId(vo.getPayoutId());
            }
            paymentManager.saveSimpleObjectWithSystemInfo(payment);
        }

        // Update Payment Method related object
        if (sessionManager.getUserSession().hasPermission(ApplicationPermission.AutoPayTurnOffOnRejectionOrReversal) && payment.getBillingAccount()
                .getAutoPay()) {
            payment.getBillingAccount().setAutoPay(false);
            billingAccountManager.saveSimpleObjectWithSystemInfo(payment.getBillingAccount());
        }

        if (sessionManager.getUserSession().hasPermission(ApplicationPermission.disableGenerateRefundForGRReversalEvent)) {
            return null;
        }

        RefundForPaymentReconciliationVO refundForPaymentReconciliationVO = new RefundForPaymentReconciliationVO();
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setPaymentId(payment.getId());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setAmount(Decimal.ZERO.equals(vo.getAmount()) ? payment.getPaymentAmount() : vo.getAmount());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setRefundDate(ZDateUtils.today(TzUtils.userTimeZone()));
        if (payment.isSettlementSupported()) {
            try {
                PaymentAccountingTransactionCheckUtils.checkIfRefundLocked(null, refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.getRefundDate(), null,
                        PaymentAccountingTransactionCheckUtils.OperationType.Create);
            } catch (ValidateException ve) {
                if (ve.getApiError() != null && ve.getApiError().equals(ApiError.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_CLOSED)) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TzUtils.userTimeZone());
                    calendar.setTime(refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.getRefundDate());
                    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setRefundDate(ZDateUtils.dateOf(calendar));
                }
            }
        }
        if (payment.getPaymentMethod() != null) {
            refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setPaymentMethodId(payment.getPaymentMethod().getId());
        }
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setMethodType(payment.getMethodType());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setReferenceId(vo.getCreatedGatewayReferenceId());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setSecondRefundReferenceId(vo.getCreatedGatewaySecondReferenceId());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setReasonCode(ReconciliationServiceConstant.REVERSAL);
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setGatewayState(GatewayState.Settled);
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setSettledOn(vo.getEventDateTime());
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setGatewayReasonCode(truncateGatewayReasonCode(vo.getGatewayReasonCode()));
        refundForPaymentReconciliationVO.setGatewayReason(vo.getGatewayReasonMessage());

        System.out.println("truncateGatewayReasonCode(vo.getGatewayReasonCode()... "+truncateGatewayReasonCode(vo.getGatewayReasonCode()));
        return arGatewayIntegrationService.createRefundForPaymentReconciliation(refundForPaymentReconciliationVO);
    }
```

Comment: please update the post with `truncateGatewayReasonCode` method and if you have already tried any test that as well please

Comment: Please include only relevant code; this is painful enough to read as it is. There are multiple ways this could be tested; as a *unit test* you'd check whatever the longly-named service returns. You could check the call to the service to ensure the "gateway reason code" has the expected value. You could check the call to the gateway reason code setter. Etc.